# How do you position an element inline before the first line wrap?

Tags: css

I have a little "more info" icon that I want to position inline after the last word on the first line of some wrapped text.  Just like the question mark in this example...

```
If this is my pretend ?
sentence, then I want the
icon to be in the position
where you see the question
mark... line #1 above.
```

The answer is not `float: right;` or `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;`

If I use those then it will look like this...

```
If this is my pretend     ?
sentence, then I want the
icon to be in the position
where you see the question
mark... line #1 above.
```

I want the icon to appear inline, but I don't want to actually put it inline because the text will be inserted dynamically, so determining where to put it will be cumbersome.  I would also like something light-weight, so ideally no Javascript or jQuery.

Is there a way to do this with pure CSS?

jsFiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/JTSEU/

Comment: a jsfiddle or codepen example will be helpful .. since you have restrictions on what css properties you don't want to position the more info icon with.. thx

Comment: try display: inline-block; or text-aligns

Comment: well, you say the text is dynamic, so how you plan on positioning the question mark in a specific place, without knowing how long the text will be?

Comment: @jonathan > Here's a jsfiddle showing the problem... http://jsfiddle.net/JTSEU/

Comment: @GiovanniSilveira > That's exactly my question.  How can I do that?

Comment: there is this CSS ::first-line .. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line .. but im still testing to see how that could be possible with CSS only since the first lines words will vary in length

Comment: @jonathan > if we could chain pseudo elements this would work.  I could do `:first-line:after { content: "ICON_HERE"; }`  Sadly, chaining pseudo elements was removed from the spec, although there are forces at work to change that... http://css-tricks.com/use-cases-for-multiple-pseudo-elements/

Comment: yeah I found the old spec that talked about it, but looks like the module hasnt been applied.. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#inserting0 ..

Comment: and what I'm saying is that you likely wont be able to do this without javascript, unless you want to go with justified text

Answer (score 0):

There is an article about this on here:

http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/css/positioning_inline_icon.html

Just view the source to see exactly how it's done looks quite easy.

Something like this:

```
<span class="p linkicon">
  The image is absolutely positioned relative to the containing element.
  <a style="padding-right:0px" href="yourlink">
    <img style="right:-12px" height="9" width="12" alt="external link" src="http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/style/img/ext-link.gif" />
  </a>
</span>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This shows the icons at the end of the last line of text in a text wrapped block.  I want the icon at the end of the first line.

Comment: That doesnt answer the question, just shows how to make an icon inline

Answer (score 0):

Hi for now the only way i see it posible and simply is with

```
float:left and word-break:break-all
```

Chek this fiddle maybe can help you http://jsfiddle.net/ZE2HR/ changing the max-width of the wrapper.

**The problem is that word-break breaks in any part of the word.**

Comment: It also pushes the icon out of the text.  I want it to appear inline without actually being inline.

Comment: it seem can't be posible, in the jsfiddle that i propose the a element will not leave white space i think this is the best option.